# close vote queue asks "should this question be closed" instead of "should this question be put on hold"

Tags: discussion, review, vote-to-close

I recently gained the privilege to look at the close vote queue, and something about the way it asks the question at the top of the page is confusing me.

It's my understanding that questions go through a state of being "on hold" before they are actually closed, and that the "Close Vote queue" is now the queue of questions other users flag to be put "on hold".

However, when reviewing questions here, the text a the top of the page still asks "Should this question be closed as [Insert Reason Here]".  Shouldn't this be updated to say "Should this question be put **on hold** as..." instead?  Or am I actually closing these questions?

Answer (score 5):

You are actually closing a question, the question just makes a pit stop at the "on hold" status before it actually gets labelled as closed.

Changing the text to say "on hold" would be confusing - it implies that your action would *only* put it on hold and never change it to closed, and that it would need further action to be changed to that closed status.

Think of it in code:

```
class ClosedQuestion {}

class OnHoldQuestion extends ClosedQuestion {}
```

An on hold question *is* a closed question, just labelled differently.

Comment: I guess I'm thinking of it in reverse, where a closed question is also an extension of "on hold", since it's a more specific type... it might be just because this is new to me.

Comment: What a beautiful code analogy. That said, I think it's important to note that the change from [on hold] to [closed] is fully automated. It's really just a friendlier label so the user knows it can be reopened at any point.